# ORDER BY in Comma Delimited List Using SELECT Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, csv

I am using the following code for creating the Comma Delimited List.

I wanted the sequence of the list in particular order:

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name
FROM Production.Product
SELECT @listStr
GO
```

When I tried like

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY sortOrder
SELECT @listStr
GO
```

It shows error `incorrect syntax near ' ORDER'`

Comment: What is the sortOrder?? it is not defined anywhere and it is not present in the table

Comment: sortOrder is the column name in my table

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any invalid characters in your text. The invalid characters could come from copy-paste of code, and could appear as "space" but infact are not seen that way by the interpreter.

Comment: Your query works fine ([SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82170/1)). Make sure 'BY' are English symbols and you have no special symbols between ORDER and BY

Comment: @Petio lvanov, valex 
This is the example of code I have posted but In actual am also using the Join with it, may be that coaused the error
& I didnt get any spell mestake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)() Which gives you the same comma seperated result

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @listStr = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + Name
            FROM Production.Product
            ORDER BY sortOrder
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @listStr
GO
```

Comment: STUFF just replaces the first ',' with an empty string, its the FOR XML clause that create the coma delimited list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can put an order by when getting a scalar value. And you should not need it since you are expecting only one value.

Comment: I am asking about the order of the values being deliminated in `@listStr` variable

Answer (score -1):

Almost every time you see "incorrect syntax near" in a script that appears to be correct, or has been copied and pasted from somewhere else, you likely have invalid characters in the text that are not visible, and appear as empty space.
My advice would be to open a new window and retype the whole query manually, or try and guess where the invalid characters are to clean them up.